# create authorized webclient with cxf jaxrs

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, jax-rs, cxf

I'm a beginner developer. I want to write a rest service call with "apache cxf jaxrs". To do that I create a web client. The sample code is below:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(url);
ClientConfiguration configuration = WebClient.getConfig(client);

MultivaluedHashMap headersMap = new 
MultivaluedHashMap();
headersMap.add("key","value");
client.type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").headers(headersMap);

Form form = new Form();

Response response = client.post(form);
```

The service which I'm going to call need a one way ssl authorization, so I get the server certificate and convert it to JKS to config the ssl handshake .after creating a socket how can i .  combine the web client which i created ssl socket. I don’t want to use spring frame work. Can somebody help me with a simple java sample?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The server certificate needs to be added to java CACERTS. That way your java cxf client will 'trust' the server and allow SSL.

You can do this with java keytool as follows:
(assuming your java is at D:\Java and your cert is in a file called server.cer

```
"D:\Java\bin\keytool.exe" -import -alias my_server -keystore  "D:\Java\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -file server.cer
```

Trust this certificate? [no]: answer is y

Success is indicated with: "Certificate was added to keystore"

Comment: In my question I explained that I trust the certificate which I get from client. I create a jks from certificate and add it to keystore. Then load the keystore. I also have the keyManagerFactory and trustManager Factory. Then I create an ssl socket and do handshake. But my webClient obj from cxf didn't bind with socket. And I don't know how to do it. So I get "could not send message" error.